# Tool to check if web server is following HTTP standard?

Tags: http, webserver, web-standards

I'm writing a simple HTTP server which should play nicely with most clients, but is only meant to implement a subset of HTTP 1.1.

During development it would be nice to be able to validate that the generated HTTP reponses are HTTP 1.1 compliant. Is there a tool that can do something along those lines?

Thanks /Erik

Comment: If you only implement a subset of the standard, then by definition your server will not be compliant...

Comment: Yes, but it would still be possible to check if a particular response is compliant or not. For example, make sure that headers follow the spec etc.

Comment: I think you might need to be more specific about exactly what subset of the HTTP standard your server is supposed to support.

Comment: Ordinary GET and POST requests as the first step. I might add more request methods later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a complete conformance suite, but RED does check for a number of different HTTP requirements, and finds common problems.

http://redbot.org/

Answer (score -1):

You could just write unit test cases using any http client library. Make GET and POST requests to your webserver, parse the response and make assertions. As you add additional features, add more test cases.

For example, lets say you only support url-encoded POST requests. So, you write a test case which verifies your server understands url-encoded requests and responds appropriately. Tomorrow, when you add support for multi-part support - that would be another test case altogether.

Every programming language under the sun has good support for HTTP, so writing the test case is a no-brainer.

Comment: Unfortunately the most work when writing a server is testing errornous and mean DOS like requests and no http client library will help you with this.